# How many artifacts are in Scrum in total?

Tags: scrum, agile, artifacts

I have defined that 3 main artifacts of the Scrum are

1. Product Backlog
2. Sprint Backlog
3. Product increment.

Could there be more artifacts in Scrum such as "Definition of Done" or "Sprint Goal".
Different topics contradict each other on this question.

https://www.visual-paradigm.com/scrum/what-are-scrum-artifacts/

I there any universal source?

Comment: Yes, it's called the [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/). But "artifacts" is an english word you can use however pleases you.

Comment: The "universal source" would be the Scrum Guide, which defines only 3 artifacts, the ones you mentioned (product backlog, sprint backlog, product increment). Artifacts, per the definition of the word, are usually usable "objects". The DoD or Sprint Goals are not really objects, although are useful, so you might see why they get extended to mean artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Scrum Alliance](https://www.scrumalliance.org/learn-about-scrum/scrum-elearning-series/scrum-artifacts) as well as to the [Scrum guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) there are 3 Scrum artifacts: the Product Backlog, the Sprint Backlog, and the product Increment.

As far as Scrum itself is concerned, there are no more artifacts there. Of course you can modify Scrum in any way. However, I'm not sure that it still could be called Scrum.

Answer (score 1):

The [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts) is the definitive guide of what artifacts are in Scrum: The Product Backlog, Sprint Backlog and Increment.

It would certainly be possible to make a case for the "Definition of Done" or "Sprint Goal" being artifacts, but that is not stated explicitly in the Scrum Guide.

As Scrum is a *framework* it leaves a lot of room for adaption. Hence you may see lots of different views and possibly even contradictions around what constitutes a Scrum artifact.

It is also worth noting that the Scrum Guide itself is not set in stone. It is reviewed frequently and there have been many updates over the years.